# Pygame is now a .whl file??

Tags: python, installation, pygame

I'm using python version 3.4.2

so I'm trying to install pygame but when I go to this website to get the apparent up-to-date file I get .whl files:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame

how do I install them, do I extract the contents to the python34 directory or something else?

Comment: what happens if you run `pip install package-name.whl`? (assuming `pip` command corresponds to Python 3.4 version).

Comment: pip install package-name.whl
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: `pip` is a shell command. Run it from the command-line, not inside Python REPL

Comment: ok I got that now, where do I put pygames whl?

Comment: it does not matter. You can put it in any temporary directory where you can run the command. You don't need the file after the installation.

Comment: I get this error pygamesname.whl is not a supported wheel file format or something

Comment: [edit] your question and include the command that you've used and the full error message. You might need to upgrade `pip`, run: `python3 -m pip install -U pip`. See [Installing from wheels](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#installing-from-wheels)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a Wheel file, Python's new built-package format.  You can find a great deal of information, including how to install them, at the [wheel documentation site](http://wheel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).